# How to merge date range if those record have same value

Tags: sql, date, gaps-and-islands

I have a problem and I need help.
I have been searching for a day and I still have no idea for it.

I would like to merge date range data from multiple to single record if those record have same value as examples below

**Example 1:**

Data

```
START_DATE / END_DATE / VALUE
01-JAN-1800 / 01-JAN-2000 / X
02-JAN-2000 / 01-JAN-4000 / X
```

Expected result

```
START_DATE / END_DATE / VALUE  
01-JAN-1800 / 01-JAN-4000 / X
```

**Example 2:**

Data

```
START_DATE / END_DATE / VALUE 
01-JAN-1800 / 01-JAN-2000 / X
02-JAN-2000 / 01-JAN-2005 / Y
02-JAN-2005 / 01-JAN-2010 / X
02-JAN-2010 / 01-JAN-4000 / X
```

Expected result

```
START_DATE / END_DATE / VALUE   
01-JAN-1800 / 01-JAN-2000 / X
02-JAN-2000 / 01-JAN-2005 / Y
02-JAN-2005 / 01-JAN-4000 / X
```

**Example 3:**

Data

```
START_DATE / END_DATE / VALUE   
01-JAN-1800 / 01-JAN-4000 / X
```

Expected result

```
START_DATE / END_DATE / VALUE   
01-JAN-1800 / 01-JAN-4000 / X
```

**Example 4:**

Data

```
START_DATE / END_DATE / VALUE
01-JAN-1800 / 01-JAN-1990 / X
02-JAN-1990 / 01-JAN-2000 / X
02-JAN-2000 / 01-JAN-2003 / Y
02-JAN-2003 / 01-JAN-2005 / Y
02-JAN-2005 / 01-JAN-2010 / X
02-JAN-2010 / 01-JAN-4000 / X
```

Expected result

```
START_DATE / END_DATE / VALUE 
01-JAN-1800 / 01-JAN-2000 / X
02-JAN-2000 / 01-JAN-2005 / Y
02-JAN-2005 / 01-JAN-4000 / X
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like gaps and islands problem. With that you'll probably find plenty of examples.

Comment: You should also tag the DBMS you're using, because it typically affects how to do this.